# Pod error when I add audioplayer to flutter

Tags: flutter, cocoapods, audio-player, flutter-packages, pod-install

I'm following a tutorial for Flutter, which uses the audioplayer package. Unfortunately, when I try to run the project after adding the package, it doesn't work anymore... I tried everything I found around, but nothing seems to work: I get errors like

"Error running pod install Error launching application on iPhone 13."

I tried to uninstall cocoapods, reinstall pod, but every time I get a lot of errors... I don't know what to do anymore... [this is an example of what I see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8m0y4.jpg)

If I try to do "cd ios" and "pod deintegrate", when I do "pod install" [I get this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mE5Hb.jpg)...
I tried to run it on my iPhone and on Xcode and [this is what I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5AcT.png)... but I don't understand why, because I added it in the "pubspec.yaml" file...

Comment: have you tried running it on a real device or opening xcode and try running it there ? Often times it will give you a better idea of the issue in xcode.

Comment: I just tried... I updated my question with what I got...